# joomla pagination not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

```
function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false){

    $lim0 = 0;
    $lim = 10;

    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();

    $db->setQuery('SELECT name,email,id,profile_value from y0sov_users,y0sov_user_profiles where y0sov_users.id=y0sov_user_profiles.user_id and profile_key="profile.department" LIMIT 0,10');
    $rL=&$db->loadAssocList();


    if (empty($rL)) {
        $jAp->enqueueMessage($db->getErrorMsg(),'error'); return;
    }     
    else 
    {
        $db->setQuery('SELECT FOUND_ROWS();');  
        jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
        $pageNav = new JPagination( $db->loadResult(), $lim0, $lim );
        foreach($rL as $r) {
        echo '<div id="values">';
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>'.$r.'</li>';
        echo '</div>';
        }


    echo $pageNav->getListFooter(); 
    }

} 

}
?>
```

The values are not displaying. I am new to Joomla so pardon me if I am missing something really fundamental.

Comment: Missing closing `<ul>` tag. Old database query methods. I would use a class rather then ID in your `div`. Are you calling the function anywhere, if so, how? Any errors in the error log? Have you turned on error reporting? What version of Joomla are you using?

Answer (score 0):

nice try!
This is not the way to do it in joomla.
You do not need to create the ul li structure.

The echo $pageNav->getListFooter();  does it for you.

I assume that the code above belongs to a component.
Place the echo $pageNav->getListFooter();
part inside the appropriate file in the tmpl folder of the view. As far I can see in your code, you only use the view.html.php file?

This is not completely wrong, but you do not use joomla standards and you may face problems on cases such as creating menu items of such a type.

Usually we  create the pagination object in the model and we just get it in the view.html.php  file. Finally, we echo $pageNav->getListFooter();  in the appropriate file in tmpl.

This tutorial is quite good & easy:
http://www.tutsforu.com/pagination-in-joomla-component.html